# How to get Location/Town and State by specified Pincode in android?

Tags: android

Is there any way or any google api to get the Location/town and State of specified pincode in android?

Comment: no such API, but you can get all the details by providing latitude and longitude.

Comment: @hari thanks for your comment, but how i get latitude and longitude of specified pincode?

Comment: What is meant by pincode?  Is this like a ZIP or postcode?

Comment: pincode means Zipcode

Comment: @Luke Park Yes, he is saying about that. Is there any API for that :D ?

Comment: @Vishal Suresh You should not use pincode, you can get the current lat and lon by GPS, and then with that lat and lon you can get the place name and all

Comment: @hari I don't want  my current location.I have some zip codes and i want to get their address.

Comment: ohkk. You got an answer below. (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of India, GOVERNMENT OF INDIA provide a OGD platform. They provide a service. API. Requests can be sent over HTTP. Data can be returned as JSON, XML, or JSONP.

[This Link may Help you.](https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/api)

Answer (score 1):

By typing my postcode and country into Google Maps: `0632, New Zealand`
I am presented with the selected area that I live in:

https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Auckland+0632/@-36.744195,174.6597443,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x6d0d3bf959b8543d:0x9893a342eb13de66

Thus, by querying Google's Geocoding API you can determine the LatLng position from a similar search string.  For example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=0632+NEW+ZEALAND&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Will return JSON data detailing my area.  Note that this requires an API key to use.  See the following link for more information:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro